# How to calculate the number of days between two dates in sqlite or mysql?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

How to calculate the number of days between two dates available in sqlite or mysql database table?
I have already searched it on google but couldn't found any solution.
What is proper query for getting number of days between two dates?

Comment: Use `datediff()` function on MySQL. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: I would be really curious as to how you searched for an answer to this question, so that you did not find any solutions...

Answer (score 0):

the query should look like this, MySQL:

```
SELECT datediff(current_date(), '2018-10-01') AS numberOfDays FROM dual;
```